# Visual Studio expected ';' after a function

Tags: c++, function

So, I'm trying to learn some basic C++, and I can't even get a function to work.

```
bool isInteger(std::string input)
{
    try
    {
        std::stoi(input);
        return true
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        return false
    }
}
```

Upon the first curly bracket, it says ';' expected. I don't see anything wrong with the function.

Help?

Comment: Every statement in C++ must end with `;`, even if it's the last statement in a block.

Comment: @Barmar: while I agree with the gist of your comment, it happens to be inaccurate. For example `if (true) {}` is a complete and legal statement without a semicolon. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course `;` is expected, just like:

```
bool isInteger(std::string input)
{
    try
    {
        std::stoi(input);
        return true;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: It still comes up...

Comment: Well, I accidently messed up a few things in my code...

This is my full code: https://imgur.com/a/o5Bn0

Now the error shows up in main.

Comment: @Logan you have nested `int main()` inside `int main()` cant you see it?

Comment: Oh yeah, I don't know how I missed that. Thanks.